# Chrome Developer Tools: missing source tab

Tags: google-chrome

I am missing Source tab from dev tools of chrome. Is there any setting require to get this source tab back or I need to install any different version of Chrome?

Unfortunately I don't have at least 10 reputation to post image for the same :(

Comment: Just to be clear, did you mean the "Sources" tab? What does this have to do with jquery/javascript?

Comment: Yes "Sources" tab. I tagged jquery/javascript to get answer quickly because mainly jquery/javascript developers use this tool.

Comment: Could you post an link to the image? I can inline it in the question for you.

Comment: This isn't programming question.  But I guess is it inline js?

Comment: Just right click on your chrome browser and click on inspect element and you will be able to see a dev tools. I tried to post image for the same but stack overflow did not allowed me because my reputation is less than 10 :(

Comment: @mnmnmnmnm We know where about source tab in dev tools.  The question is your javascript is written in inline or embedded or external?

Comment: Sorry Praveen I thought some one wanted to know about Sources tab in dev tool. Anyway I am using external JS. But I don't think it really matter for this problem.

Comment: It didn't work for me; the source tab has vanished.  Incredibly poor design.

Answer (score 7):

This resolve my issue. please follow the below 3 steps.
[image: Click on message icon at top right]
[image: Source tab will appear]
[image: Right click and move to top]